# AngularJS: Binding textarea to object property - infdig error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, textarea, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am relatively new to AngularJS and I think there is an infdig error in my code due to the binding of the textarea through ng-model, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

The text areas have the values that I am currently expecting. Reading previous posts on the topic, the infdig error appears when the values are being modified inside of an ng-repeat. However, I do not think that I am modifying any 
values inside of the ng-repeat.

**Controller**:

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $location, fetchService){
    ...
    $scope.problemFocus = {};
    $scope.changeProblem = function(id) {
    $location.path('/problems')
    $http.get('/api/problems/' + id).success(function(data){
        $scope.problemFocus = data;
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in problemFocus">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td><textarea class="problem-property-value" form="properties-edit" ng-model="[value]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have attempted to fix this error by changing ng-model="[value]" to ng-binding="[value]", but this results in an empty text area. Changing it to ng-model="problemFocus[value]", the text areas become empty, and in addition, when typing in the text area, the value is added as the key of a new column.

**Update**
I figured out that it should have been ng-model="value" not ng-model="[value]". This fixes the infdig error.

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…2%3A%5B%5B%22A%3A%22%2C%22B%3A%22%2C%22C%3A%22%2C%22D%3A%22%5D%5D%7D%5D%5D

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…2%3A%5B%5B%22A%3A%22%2C%22B%3A%22%2C%22C%3A%22%2C%22D%3A%22%5D%5D%7D%5D%5D

Comment: @boolean_ring please add errors as edits to your question, not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying how you access your value inside ng-model as follows

```
<td><textarea class="problem-property-value" form="properties-edit" ng-model="problemFocus[value]"></textarea></td>
```

Comment: When I change it, the error goes away. However, the textareas become empty.

Comment: What happens when you type in it? Does the model update correctly?

Comment: When I type in the text area, a new row is added at the bottom of the table with the value under the key column. 
Edit: the value was added not input